# Efficient way of paging with MongoDB and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We are creating an application MongoDB as database and we are using [official C# driver for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/). We have one collection which contains thousands of records and we want to create list with paging. I have gone through documentation but there is not efficient way of paging with MongoDB C# official driver.

My requirement is to exactly fetch only 50 records from database. I have seen many examples but that get all collection and perform skip and take via LINQ which is not going to work in our case as we don't want to fetch thousand of records in memory.

Please provide any example code or link for that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SetLimit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) on the cursor that represents the query. That will limit the results from `MongoDB`, not only in memory:

```
var cursor = collection.FindAll(); // Or any other query.
cursor.SetLimit(50); // Will only return 50.
foreach (var item in cursor)
{
    // Process item.
}
```

You can also use [`SetSkip`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) to set a skip (surprisingly):

```
cursor.SetSkip(10);
```

**Note:** You must set those properties on the cursor *before* enumerating it. Setting those after will have no effect.

---

By the way, even if you do only use `Linq`'s `Skip` and `Take` you won't be retrieving thousands of documents. `MongoDB` [automatically batches](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-batches) the result by size (first batch is about `1mb`, the rest are `4mb` each) so you would only get the first batch and take the first 50 docs out of it. More on

---

**Edit:** I think there's some confusion about `LINQ` here:

> that get all collection and perform skip and take via LINQ which is not going to work in our case as we don't want to fetch thousand of records in memory.

`Skip` and `Take` are extension methods on both `IEnumerable` **and** `IQueryable`. `IEnumerable` is meant for in memory collections, **but** `IQueryable` operations are [translated by the specific provider](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) (the C# driver in this case). So the above code is equivalent with:

```
foreach (var item in collection.AsQueryable().SetLimit(50))
{
    // Process item.
}
```