# Mongodb C# Query Sort exceeded memory limit of

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have 2 weeks learning and working with MongoDB, I'm building a simple WinForm APP with a DataGridview.

Everything was working fine but I added more than 1.000.000 documents and now it show me this error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in..'

I've checked all my weekend google how to use Aggreate allowDiskUse:true but it doesnt works either.

Thanks.

```
public void ReadAllDocuments()
{
    List<Clientes> list = collection.AsQueryable().OrderBy(q => q.Nombre).ToList();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should limit the amount of items retrieved from MongoDb, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262020/efficient-way-of-paging-with-mongodb-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: By calling ToList() you are forcign the retrieval of 1m documents. Irrespective of Mongo's memory limitations, you are not going to get that in a DataGridView.

Comment: @RuiJarimba Thanks a lot!! Yeah I should limit it! I was learning and I didnt know. I created a for loop to over saturate my DB. Now I understand the rules. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to pass in aggregator options to the queryable.

```
collection.AsQueryable(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true })
```

However, usually, going over the document limit with a sort is a sign that your query isn't optimal. You may want to rethink your db design or query so that you don't have to sort such a large set of data.

Comment: Thanks you very much!! it's finally works. I understand I'm really not going to handle so many documents, it was just curious I created a for loop to over saturate my DB, really I have not worked with such a huge project to date. Thanks for your tips my friend. I will continue learning.